# Characters not displaying on site from database?

Tags: php, html

In my database I have lots of

```
“
```

Do not confuse this with

```
"
```

These do not show up on my website, is there a way to get them out and display them on my site without converting them all to a html char code?

Im using PHP.

Comment: Are they not showing up at all or are browsers displaying something different? Is the page encoding set to UTF-8?

Comment: Could you show us a [short, self-contained](http://www.sscce.org/) bit of code that displays this behaviour, specifically the bits where you put the data into the database and where you fetch it again for displaying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming MySQL and Apache.

Before any other queries, run this query:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Also make sure that your site is using utf-8. In your .htaccess, add:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .js .xml .json .rss .atom
```

Then, in your `head` on your page, add

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: These are good suggestions, but if this is affecting a PHP script, the OP would also have to include `.php` in the list of file formats specified in the `.htaccess` file :)

Comment: What is the character encoding you're using for the MySQL database, table, and field containing your data?

Comment: Essentially, PHP sucks at this. I pretty much always replace them with &ldquo; and &rdquo; on insertion to the database. This is one of the main reasons I'm considering moving to Python for web dev.